# Animate left navigation

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery

I am trying to do some branding in SharePoint 2010, how can I make the left navigation as http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/ 'Show/Hide Left Slide Menu'

The code which I try left navigation hides totally but I want to keep some 10% of it.

```
> $(document).ready(function(){   $('#mnu').click(function () {
  $('#s4-leftpanel').slideToggle('2000',"swing", function () {
      // Animation complete.
      });   
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving class with css `margin-left: 25px;` (or more) when the menu is hidden. But when the button is clicked (to show the menu) remove this class from the `#s4-leftpanel`